# Getting "XPath error: Invalid predicate", while trying to use an Xpath that contains greek letters

Tags: xpath, unicode, scrapy

From this webpage: [page](http://www.xe.gr/property/poliseis%7Cgis%7Cdovra%7C271338857.html?mode=spec) I am trying to build a crawler that is going to extract "Μακεδονία > Ν. Ημαθίας > Δ. Δοβρά" from the "Περιοχή:" field.

--> See a screenshot of the item:
See Link no.2 below

In order to do this, I am intended to use XPath to focus on "Περιοχή:" and then use the following-sibling keyword to access and extract the text "Μακεδονία > Ν. Ημαθίας > Δ. Δοβρά", because the td that contains it can be in a different location in other webpages (but always after the tr with the text "Περιοχή:") or even missing.
See  Link no.3 below

---

In scrapy shell I am testing the following:

```
x = response.xpath(u"//th[@text()=u'Περιοχή:']/text()").extract()
```

expecting to get x = [u"Περιοχή:"]

but instead I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //th[@text()=u'\u03a0\u03b5\u03c1\u03b9\u03bf\u03c7\u03ae:']/text()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link no.2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yChN3.png

Comment: Link no.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnd9M.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying unicode encoding twice, you shouldn't specify that in xpath since it's already an unicode string.

i.e.

```
# this:
u"//th[@text()=u'Περιοχή:']/text()"
# should be this:
u"//th[text()='Περιοχή:']/text()"
```

Notice no `u` before the text and you don't need @ before `text()` either because it's an xpath function not a node attribute.